# How to change the fillColor of a SKShapeNode within the didBegin contact function?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skshapenode, skphysicscontact

My goal is to change the fillColor of a SKShapeNode as soon as that node collides with another Node. I do know how to edit the physics body at the point of collision but I couldn't manage to figure out how to change properties like fill- or strokeColor of a Node.

The SKShapeNode:

```
    func addBrick() -> SKShapeNode {

    let brick = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: -100, y: -20, width: 200, height: 40), cornerRadius: 20)
    brick.fillColor = .blue
    brick.strokeColor = .blue
    brick.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 200, height: 40))
    brick.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -50)
    brick.zPosition = 2

    brick.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BrickCategory
    brick.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PlayerCategory
    brick.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PlayerCategory

    return brick
}
```

Then I test the contact between the player and the brick:

```
    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    switch contactMask {
    case PlayerCategory | BrickCategory:
        print("")



    default:
        print("Unknown collision")
    }
}
```

I do know that I can make changes to the physics body itself by using

```
contact.bodyB.node?.//make changes here
```

, but I don't know how to change the fillColor of bodyB for example to red.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an `SKNode` `node` that you know should be an `SKShapeNode`, then you can cast it like:

```swift
if let shapeNode = node as? SKShapeNode {
    shapeNode.fillColor = .red
}
```

Comment: For `node` I get the error: "Static member 'node' cannot be used on instance of type 'GameScene' Insert SKNode".  So I changed it to `contact.bodyB.node` but know the if statement doesn't get called at all.

Comment: `node` was just an example.  The shape node in the collision may be from either `bodyA` or `bodyB`.  You have to examine the category bitmasks or names or whatever to identify which node is the correct one.  If the node you attempt to reference `as?` a shape node isn't of that type, the cast will not succeed and the `if` won't be executed.